# Reduce number of QuerySet for django project

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I am making an Entity-Review-Vote kind of system where each entity will have some reviews, and each review will have some vote (up/down)

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Review(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(user)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    ....

class Vote(models.Model):
    vote_user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    vote_review = models.ForeignKey(Review)
    vote_value = models.BooleanField() # True = Up
```

For each entity, I want to have a list of reviews, annotated with number of upvotes and downvotes for each review.

So far, my approach is to run 2 extra query for each review:

```
count_up = Vote.objects.filter(vote_review__id = X, vote_value = True)
count_down = Vote.objects.filter(vote_review__id = X, vote_value = False)
```

This returns correct result. However, the number of queries seem quite inefficient.

May I know if there is a better way to construct the queries? Or how to change the schema to better support this kind of operation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the whole vote object or just the count?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the view? Are these queries being done in a loop for all reviews? If so you can probably use annotations.

Comment: @Daniel Basically I want to display all reviews for a particular entity, each review with information count_up and count_down.
A similar example is something like [image](http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/promo/reviews/feature_browse.jpg)
(I am free to write the code for this part, but I havent since I am not quite sure about this part)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the count then you should just use [count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count)

> Returns an integer representing the number of objects in the database matching the QuerySet. The count() method never raises exceptions.

```
count_up = Vote.objects.filter(vote_review__id = X, vote_value = True).Count()
count_down = Vote.objects.filter(vote_review__id = X, vote_value = False).Count()
```

This will modify the queries to just return the number of objects that the query creates and stops it from spending time returning the models.